# Handlebars for each template not working in Node

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm using Node.js, Express, and Handlebars to render template on client side. I'm not getting any errors, but the template is not getting populated.

view: detail.hbs

```
<table id="attachmentTable" class="table table-condensed box-bottom-space"> 
  <tbody>
    ...                         
  </tbody>
</table>

// The back slash before the curly brackets are required, without it errors out.
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  \{{#each this}}
  <tr>
    <td class="attachments">
      <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> &nbsp;
      <a target="_blank" href="/uploads/\{{this}}">\{{this}}</a>
      <a class="deleteAttachmentIcon text-danger" href="javascript:;" data-deletefile="\{{this}}"><span class="fa fa-remove"></span></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  \{{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/handlebars-v4.0.5.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function($) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/processes/upload/{{processes._id}}',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(response){
        if(response.success){
          console.log(response.file);
          var rTemplate = $("#rowTemplate").html();
          var crTemplate = Handlebars.compile(rTemplate);
          $("#attachmentTable body").append(crTemplate(response.file));   
        }           
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is the response from server:

> {"success":true,"msg":"The file(s) has been Upladed Successfully!","file":["June Updates1-1519927100102.docx","export-11-03-2017-1519927100103.xls"]}

What am I missing?

Comment: This question can be closed with the "typo or not repro" reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking too hard at the other code:

```
$("#attachmentTable body").append(crTemplate(response.file));
```

You probably meant to select `tbody` here, not `body`.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing... It always help to get a second set of eyes. Thank you!

Comment: @user752746 Happens to the best of us. Remember to upvote and/or accept the answer if it helped you :)